# Replace first and last character upon condition (which method is faster)?

Tags: java, string, optimization, replace

I have a list of thousands of strings that may come in the form:

> word

or

> "more than one word"

I want to remove the "" whenever they are present, so that I can save the string to my DB.

I'm wondering which method is faster:

1. Using `line.replace("\"","");`
2. Validating that first character is '"', then making a substring from character 1 to length - 1.

Or even, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Both methods will need to iterate over almost entire string, but `substring` will not have to compare every character with `"` so it will be probably faster.

Comment: Pre-optimization is evil, just saying. Unless it becomes a problem, you shouldn't worry about it. Are you having performance issues?

Comment: **line.replace** iterates each char, compares and stores it in a new buffer array.

on the other hand **line.substring** internally uses JNI with Arrays.copyOfRange to create a new string. 

line.substring would probably be faster.

Comment: @Vince - I'm not sure this is preoptimization. To me (naively), its observing Big-O type stuff. I try to select algorithms and implementations with memory/space/time tradeoffs in mind. Why the roll the dice when you can select something known to perform to requirements? Or why wait for it to become a problem?

Comment: @jww Pre-optimization is performing any optimizations before you know they're needed. If he feels that he'll need to scale up his app, and his current system won't scale, THEN it would be a problem. But spending time trying to optimize things that might not need to be optimize wastes a lot of time, which results in slower progress. Although this could fit within a "time complexity" kind of debate, he has shown no prior research towards this situation on that level. He's worried about improving performance, yet doesn't tell us whether it's actually needed or not, which falls under preoptimizing

Comment: @Vince - Oh, that's the "never time to do it right, always time to do it over" argument :) D.r Jon Bentley said it another way: *"If it doesn't have to be correct, I can make it as fast as you'd like it to be"*...

Comment: @jww Get out of the habit of trying to optimize prematurly before you aquire deadlines for projects (have a job or start freelancing). Unless the performance boost is actually needed, get the project finished. Once it's finished, profile it to see where you can *really* improve performance. Otherwise, you could be wasting time looking into optimizations that might not have as much of an impact as you may think, or may not be as needed as some other part of the project

Comment: @Vince - I don't like the tradeoff. As it stands, I usually meet deadlines and my code rarely takes bug reports. The last time one of my libraries took a bug report was 3 years ago (the libraries are used in US Financial, US Federal and US DoD). I'm not sure what the benefit is to finishing faster when the cost is incorrectness and bugs.

Comment: @jww If you wanna continue this conversation, please create a chat. No one said anything about buggy code. It's about optimizing something that may not need optimization. You meeting deadlines while preoptimizing doesn't mean EVERYONE will be able to (their research may take longer, with shorter deadlines). If it works *and doesn't cause problems*, you shouldn't waste time worrying about it. He's wondering which method is faster with no reason as to why he wants to improve his current method; I was just letting him know that he should finish his project before worrying, unless he has problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method is faster. It will perform at most one character comparison and one array copy, instead of comparing all characters in the string with the " character.